# Azure AD Devices, Issue Updating Policies

Tags: windows, azure, policy

We have several Windows 10 Pro computers that are joined through Azure AD. What I would like to have is our logo as the sign-in image when the computer starts up. Upon some research, it said to go to gpedit.msc > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > User Accounts. Under the setting select "Apply the default account picture to all users". I selected "Enabled" and saved.

In where the account pictures are stored, I updated it with our logo image. After restarting my computer (where the setting was set on), the image appeared. However, on the other computers I am not seeing this. I wondered if it was because they are Azure AD devices, but cannot seem to find anything helpful.

Am I doing something wrong with the configuration of these settings?

Answer (score 0):

Are you placing the image on each local machine (or an image), or is the picture stored on a network location? Additionally, if you're using local group policy, the setting may be getting overwritten by a domain group policy. The GPO should be asking for a file path/name, so you could test it using a network location to see if that works across more than one machine, especially if you can use domain group policy, which is recommended over local GP.